# Samsung SyncMaster 570V TFT turns off and back on about every 10s

Tags: display

My monitor will, about every 10s, turn quickly off then on.  This happens even in the BIOS.  I have searched the web, but I haven't found anything that looks like a similar problem.

I'm running a Samsung SyncMaster 570V tft moniter off a Dell PowerEdge 2850 with an ATI Radeon 7000 graphics card over VGA.

[Edit] I have tried plugging it into a different computer (My macbook pro 2010 through an adapter), and the issue doesn't persist.

[Edit] I just tried plugging it into the other VGA port on my machine (it has 2), and the issue vanished.  I don't know why, maybe that port's broken, or maybe it only happens some of the time.  either way, it's fixed.  Thank you so much for your time trying to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To help idientify the culprit:

- Check the same monitor on a different computer.
- If you have more than one video output on your computer, test the monitor on both outputs.
- Check the same computer in a different monitor.
- Try with a different power cable
- If possible, try with a different data cable. (Some monitors have detachable data cables, others don't).

If the issue still persists in all above cases, I recommend you either acuire a new monitor or take it to maintenance.

Answer (score 1):

If that's happening in the BIOS that's a red flag that it's the monitor.  I would say swap cables but a bad cable typically just causes distortion in color or picture, not this on and off problem.  Still look at your power cable, maybe try a different machine and from there it's between you and the manufacturer.

Answer (score 0):

If you unplug the monitor from the computer, but keep the screen on, does the issue persist? If not, then it's the monitor.

You could change the cable to see if that makes a difference.

Also, swap the cables over if you have more than 1 output.

Some monitors have built in HDMI ports and similar, you could try attaching it to a DVD player (if you have the cables/connections) to test each monitor, again helping to rule out if it is the card or not!

Comment: I don't have 2 monitors.